# Why we need to restart Tomcat once a .class file has been loaded?

Tags: java, tomcat

Could anyone please explain me why I need to restart the Tomcat server, once a `.class` file has been loaded into the server?

Answer (score 3):

Default behavior is you have to restart. when you restart the tomcat then and then only the class loader runs again and the changes effects.

How ever you can  [`configure`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) it with [`reloadable`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute.

```
reloadable=true
```

Note: Think twice while enabling this, as a little performance pain on tomcat and effects the existing requests on the fly(regarding the changes). Be careful.

Here you can find the [`Manager`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html) and see the heading `Reload An Existing Application`

Comment: where should I find reloadable attribute attribute in tomcat.

Comment: @Venkataramareddy updated with links.

Comment: when jsp files are loaded tomcat checks the timestamp of already available jsp and the newly added jsp file,but when we load classes why should we restart tomcat?why it is not comparing timestamp ,just like it is doing for jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Apache Tomcat WebServer doesn't have the ability to recognize the changes made in the files and restart itself, unless this feature ([reloadable](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute) is set to `true`:

```
reloadable=true
```

In this way, the server monitors the directories where the `.class` files are stored. If a change is made, it will restart itself.